# How to use foreach loop in formula field on a crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm having a foreach loop in my web application. I need to use this loop in crystal report's formula field. I'm new to crystal reports and I have no idea with how to write it in formula field. Can anyone help me?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            type = (dr["color"]).ToString();
            if (color == "red")
            {
                red_total = red_total + Convert.ToDouble(dr["amount"]);
            }
            else if (color == "blue")
            {
                bl_total = bl_total + Convert.ToDouble(dr["amount"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two formula fields:

```
//{@red}
if {table.color}="red" then
  1
else
  0

//{@blue}
if {table.color}="blue" then
  1
else
  0
```

Add a crosstab to your report.
Add these two fields to the summary section (lower right).
Add row and column grouping, if desired.

Alternate:
Add these two fields to Details section
Add a summary for each of these fields.